# Page translation of process code section in Linux. Why does the Page Table Entry get 0 for some pages?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

For some reason, I need to translate the virtual address of the code section to physical address. I did following experiment:

1. I get the virtual address from the start_code and end_code in mm_struct of process A, which are the initial address and final address of the executable code.
2. I get the CR3 of process A.
3. I translate the virtual address to physical address page by page. For example, there are 10 pages for code section in process A. I will translate 10 virtual address of each beginning of the page.
4. I found out some pages will get Page Table Entry(PTE) == 0.Some pages could successfully translate to a physical address.
5. I tried Firefox and Minicom as my Process, and both of them will get into situation.

I guess my question is: could anyone explain to me why PTE == 0? Does it mean these pages have been swap out to disk? If this is the case, how can I find these pages?

Thanks for any input!!

Comment: Is this in kernel mode (like from a convention device driver) or user mode?

Comment: Thanks for your asking. Actually, this neither in kernel mode nor user mode. I am doing forensics on another computer. Assume I have a memory dump 4G file, CR3 of process A, start_code and end_code (virtual address) of process A. I need to find out the executable code of process A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you are trying to perform page table introspection without using the kernel APIs for it. Note that the address space is arranged in a red-black tree of vm_area_struct structs and you should probably use the APIs that traverse them. The mappings might change at any time so using the proper locking for these data structures is necessary.

For example, see the get_user_pages() function. It can be used to swap-in and temporarily pin the pages into memory. Using this function for page table introspection is usually asked for because once have the physical address in hand then the kernel can swap out the page at any time.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to do the paging translation without kernel APIs. As I have described in above comments, I am trying to find out the process executable code from a memory dump. But the question is why PTE==0 for some pages of process executable code.

Comment: When the kernel maps the executable file into the address space of the process, some of the pages are not loaded. Actually, unless the executable calls mlock(), only the code that actually runs will cause page faults that will load pages for the file into RAM. The PTEs that are zero correspond parts of the code that did not run, and therefore did not 'fault-in'.

Comment: This is especially useful for execution time. Some compilations result in very large executables (think of C++ with heavy template lifting). It would be wasteful both in latency and memory resources for the kernel to load the entire executable code.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I guess have two more questions. 1: Is kernel going to swap out some pages of application executable code to disk in order to save memory? 2. Is there any way to force load these pages with PTE==0 to memory?

Comment: I think this answers it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355790/how-to-make-every-page-of-a-process-in-the-page-table-present